# jest.mock Cannot access 'xxx' before initialization

Tags: jestjs

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to mock an external module in my React testing setup using Jest. I'm attempting to mock some appSettings that is set in _app on my nextjs app, but I keep encountering a "ReferenceError: Cannot access '_appsettings' before initialization" error.

Here's the simplified structure of my code:

I have a DonorSelector component that relies on an external module/import called appSettings.

I've created a mock for appSettings in a separate file, and I'm using jest.mock to replace the real module with the mock in my test file.

Despite this, I'm consistently seeing the "ReferenceError" pointing to "_appsettings."

```
// Inside my test file

import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { DonorSelector } from "../src/views/DonorSelector";
import { appSettings } from "../mocks/app-settings"; // Import appSettings from the mock file

// Mock the appSettings module with the imported mock values
jest.mock("../src/helpers/app-settings.helper", () => ({
  ...appSettings,
}));

describe("DonorSelector", () => {
  it("should receive appSettings with mock values", () => {
    // Render the DonorSelector component with the provided appSettings
    render(<DonorSelector content={content} setLanguageCallback={() => {}} />);
    
    // Check if appSettings with mock values is available in the component
    expect(screen.getByTestId("app-settings")).toHaveTextContent(
      JSON.stringify(appSettings)
    );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `jest.mock()` are silently hoisted, which means they are put at the top of your file.

For example:

```js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { appSettings } from "../mocks/app-settings";

jest.mock("../src/helpers/app-settings.helper", () => ({
  ...appSettings,
}));

describe("DonorSelector", () => {
  it("should receive appSettings with mock values", () => {
    
  });
});
```

is turned into:

```js
// hoisted
jest.mock("../src/helpers/app-settings.helper", () => ({
  ...appSettings,
}));

import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { appSettings } from "../mocks/app-settings";

describe("DonorSelector", () => {
  it("should receive appSettings with mock values", () => {
    
  });
});
```

Jest does this because you always want mocks to happen before imports, so it's automated.

Because of that, your `appSettings` is not imported yet.

To fix it, you can use [`jest.requireActual()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) or a simple `require()`:

```js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

jest.mock("../src/helpers/app-settings.helper", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../mocks/app-settings"),
}));

describe("DonorSelector", () => {
  it("should receive appSettings with mock values", () => {

  });
});
```

---

You can also try use the following structure (with a `__mocks__` folder):

```js
src
 ├──helpers
 │   ├── __mocks__
 │   │      └──app-settings.helper.js
 │   └──app-settings.helper.js
test
 └──your-test-file.test.js
```

Then you would just have to do this:

```js
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

jest.mock("../src/helpers/app-settings.helper");

describe("DonorSelector", () => {
  it("should receive appSettings with mock values", () => {

  });
});
```

You can read more here: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules